# How do I resize rows in a table differently?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, multicolumn, cline

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table}\label{tab:1}
\centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l | @{}C@{} |}%\hline
\cline{2-2}
&$R_{E}=\Biggl(\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{1}{R_3}\Biggr)^{-1}$  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}||}{Theoretical} &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}||}{Application} &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And displayed

[image]

The `R_E` line, I try to make is equal to the top and bottom spaces. Theoretical line should be 1cm and the Application line should be 2cm. The code I added adds an error. How should this code change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of *ad hoc* commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table}\label{tab:1}
\centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\makebiggermath}[1]{%
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \makeheight{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0+10pt}%
  \box0
}
\newcommand{\makeheight}[1]{%
  \settoheight{\dimen0}{T}% a capital letter
  \rule[-\dimexpr(#1-\dimen0)/2]{0pt}{#1}%
}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l | @{}C@{} |}%\hline
\cline{2-2}
&\makebiggermath{
  R_{E}=\Biggl(\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{1}{R_3}\Biggr)^{-1}
}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\makeheight{1cm}Theoretical} & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}|}{\makeheight{2cm}Application} & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm wondering why you are using `\multicolumn`, a solution for the Theoratical / Application part might be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table}\label{tab:1}
\centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l | @{}C@{} |}%\hline
\cline{2-2}
&$R_{E}=\Biggl(\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{1}{R_3}\Biggr)^{-1}$  \\ \hline
\rule{0pt}{1cm} {Theoretical} &  \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{2cm} {Application} &  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

maybe you have to have this in a "hidden cell" as now it is added to the cell.

Comment: The reason why I use `\multicolumn` is that it is a different table image. If you suggest a different table image I try to add it to my document. In the meantime @egreg has provided the exact solution I want.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to draw an invisible line (of zero width) and the desired height and depth (below the baseline).

For example `\rule[-4mm]{0mm}{10mm}` draws a line of zero width (therefore invisible) of 10 mm height and 4mm depth.

The command `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` allows to modify the spacing between the text of a cell and its border.

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Table}\label{tab:1}
\centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l | @{}C@{} |}%\hline
\cline{2-2}
&$R_{E}=\Biggl(\dfrac{1}{R_1}+\dfrac{1}{R_2}+\dfrac{1}{R_3}\Biggr)^{-1}$ \rule[-6mm]{0mm}{15mm} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}||}{Theoretical} & \rule[-4mm]{0mm}{10mm} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{2cm}||}{Application} & \rule[-4mm]{0mm}{20mm} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

the output is :

[image: tableau]

Comment: I learned new information from your MWE.